# Create catagorical data with weight

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` like below:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['user1', 1, 10], ['user1', 2, 25], ['user2', 2, 20], ['user3', 3, 30], ['user4', 3, 50]]), columns=['UserId', 'Dim', 'Count'])
>>> df
  UserId Dim Count
0  user1   1    10
1  user1   2    25
2  user2   2    20
3  user3   3    30
4  user4   3    50
```

I want to use `Dim` column as dimension, for this I'm doing:

```
>>> df_cat = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Dim'])
>>> df_cat
  UserId Count  Dim_1  Dim_2  Dim_3
0  user1    10      1      0      0
1  user1    25      0      1      0
2  user2    20      0      1      0
3  user3    30      0      0      1
4  user4    50      0      0      1
```

But instead of `0` or `1`, I want to associate value in `Count` column as weight ie. my expected output should look like:

```
  UserId Count Dim_1 Dim_2 Dim_3
0  user1    10    10     0     0
1  user1    25     0    25     0
2  user2    20     0    20     0
3  user3    30     0     0    30
4  user4    50     0     0    50
```

Currently I'm achieving this using `for` loops:

```
for i, row in df_cat.iterrows():
    for col in df_cat.columns:
        if(row[col] == 1):
            df_cat.loc[i, col]=df_cat.Count[i]
```

Let me know if there is better way to do this instead of using 2 `for` loops as looping takes time since the actual dataset is huge.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) for reshape and add to original with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot(columns='Dim', values='Count').fillna(0).add_prefix('Dim_')
df_cat = df[['UserId','Count']].join(df1)
print (df_cat)
  UserId Count Dim_1 Dim_2 Dim_3
0  user1    10    10     0     0
1  user1    25     0    25     0
2  user2    20     0    20     0
3  user3    30     0     0    30
4  user4    50     0     0    50
```

Your solution should be changed with seelct only added columns with [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and multiple by column `Count`, but necessary cast to integers:

```
df_cat = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Dim'])

c = df_cat.columns.str.startswith('Dim')
df_cat.loc[:, c] = df_cat.loc[:, c].mul(df['Count'].astype('int'), axis=0)
print (df_cat)
  UserId Count  Dim_1  Dim_2  Dim_3
0  user1    10     10      0      0
1  user1    25      0     25      0
2  user2    20      0     20      0
3  user3    30      0      0     30
4  user4    50      0      0     50
```

---

```
df_cat = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Dim'])

c = df_cat.columns.str.startswith('Dim')

df_cat.loc[:, c] = df_cat.loc[:, c] * df['Count'].values.astype(np.int)[:, None]
print (df_cat)
  UserId Count  Dim_1  Dim_2  Dim_3
0  user1    10     10      0      0
1  user1    25      0     25      0
2  user2    20      0     20      0
3  user3    30      0      0     30
4  user4    50      0      0     50
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: With my actual dataset, I'm running into memory issue with both the approaches. `for` loop also taking time but seems to perform faster than both approaches.

Comment: @sud29 - Can you check `df_cat.loc[:, c] = df_cat.loc[:, c] * df['Count'].values.astype('int')[:, None]` instead last row of code?

Comment: Still it's crashing, I'm wondering if there is any way to do it using sparse matrix.

Comment: @sud29 - what failed? `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Dim'])` ?